# Batch file console output into a log file

Tags: batch-file, console, output

Im quite new to using bat files as a script.  I'm doing this in windows and  I'm wondering if theres an easy to way to out the contents of the console to an output log???  Thanks

Comment: `some command>>logfile.txt`  ?

Answer (score 1):

As npocmaka posted in his comment, you can redirect the output of any command executed into a text file.

- `echo 123>log.txt` will write 123 into the file log.txt. The file will be **overwritten**.
- `echo 123>>log.txt` will **append** 123 at the end of the text file.
- If you want to overwrite an existing log file at the beginning of your script, you should start with `type nul>log.txt` and use `command>>log.txt`. This way you will always have a "fresh" log file containing the log for one full execution of your script.